# Authentication - SOCKS 5

Tags: c++, winapi, socks

I am writing a SOCKS 5 server which talks with a SOCKS 5 client (maxthon browser). I got it to work without authentication. However, when I added authentication,

client sends user/pass to server
server validates user/pass

server sends response to client

```
+----+--------+
|VER | STATUS |
+----+--------+
| 1  |   1    |
+----+--------+
```

VER = 0x01
STATUS = 0x00 (success)

1. Am I right to assume that this is the end of the authentication?

After this I try to read data from the client,

```
+----+-----+-------+------+----------+----------+
|VER | CMD |  RSV  | ATYP | DST.ADDR | DST.PORT |
+----+-----+-------+------+----------+----------+
| 1  |  1  | X'00' |  1   | Variable |    2     |
+----+-----+-------+------+----------+----------+
```

However the bytes read at this point don't equal to the bytes expected by the sizeof this structure. The bytes read == 0.

2. What is the issue?

If I take out the authentication my server works fine. However I wanted to get it working with it.

**EDIT**

Here is the code after the server authenticates the client:

```
    socks5_login SOCKS5_Login;
    if (Str::Compare(UserName, PUCHAR("test")) == 0 && Str::Compare(Password, PUCHAR("test")) == 0) {

        SOCKS5_Login.Version = 0x01;
        SOCKS5_Login.Status  = 0x00;
        if (Http::SendProxyData(Settings->Sock, PCHAR(&SOCKS5_Login), sizeof(socks5_login), Settings->Func) != TRUE)
            return FALSE;

        UCHAR Status;
        Settings->Func.Recv(Settings->Sock, PCHAR(Status), sizeof(UCHAR), 0);

        if (Status != NO_ERROR)
            return FALSE;

        /*
            The SOCKS request is formed as follows:
                +----+-----+-------+------+----------+----------+
                |VER | CMD |  RSV  | ATYP | DST.ADDR | DST.PORT |
                +----+-----+-------+------+----------+----------+
                | 1  |  1  | X'00' |  1   | Variable |    2     |
                +----+-----+-------+------+----------+----------+
        */

        socks5_request Request;
        if (Http::ReadProxyData(Settings->Sock, PCHAR(&Request.SOCKS5_Header), sizeof(socks5_header), Settings->Func) != TRUE)
            return FALSE;

        if (Request.SOCKS5_Header.Command != 1/*CONNECT*/ && 
            Request.SOCKS5_Header.AddressType != 1 /*IPv4*/ &&
            Request.SOCKS5_Header.Version != 5 /*SOCKS Version 5*/)
            return FALSE;

        // ...
```

When reading `Request.SOCKS5_Header`, Http::ReadProxyData() function returns FALSE ( recv() returned 0 ).

Comment: That's how RFC1929 works, so yeah. Are you sure the client's happy with your response?

Comment: @tadman If thats the case, how come I cannot receive the structure after the authentication response is sent to the client?

Comment: It's possible you're not properly sending the response and the client is waiting for something to happen before saying anything else. Are you sure that data's "flushed" out the socket?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "flushed"?

Comment: "*The bytes read == 0*" - If `recv()` returns 0, it means the peer disconnected gracefully. Which probably means you are not sending back your responses correctly, so the client is failing on its end and closing the connection. Please show your actual code, you are likely doing something wrong with it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Updated

Comment: This  looks like C++, not C.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading a `UCHAR` after sending your authentication reply (and you are type-casting its *undefined value* to `PCHAR`, because you are not passing it to `Recv()` using the `&` address operator. So you are likely to *crash* your code!).  The client does not send a reply to your reply.  By reading that `UCHAR`, you are reading the `VER` field of the next request, which means reading the full `Request` afterwards is likely to fail.

You should NOT be reading that `UCHAR` at all.

More importantly, you are setting the `VER` field of your authentication reply to `0x01` instead of to `0x05`.  You say the number of bytes being read for the next request is 0.  That means the client is gracefully closing the connection on its end, which makes sense if you send back a malformed authentication reply.

Re-read [RFC 1928](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1928) and [RFC 1929](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1929) more carefully.  The diagrams show you the *byte sizes* of each field, not the *values* you should set the fields to (those values are described in lists following the diagrams).  For instance:

```
+----+--------+
|VER | STATUS |
+----+--------+
| 1  |   1    |
+----+--------+
```

Means the `VER` field is 1 byte in size, and `STATUS` is 1 byte in size.  Not that you should be setting the `VER` field to 1.

Also, the `if` at the end of the code you showed should be using the `||` operator instead of the `&&` operator.  Though, you really shouldn't be validating the request fields the way you are, since different conditions require you to send a different error code back to the client so it knows WHY the request failed.

Try something more like this:

```
socks5_login LoginReply;
LoginReply.Version = 5;

if (Str::Compare(UserName, PUCHAR("test")) == 0 && Str::Compare(Password, PUCHAR("test")) == 0)
    LoginReply.Status = 0; /*success*/
else
    LoginReply.Status = 1; /*failure*/

if (Http::SendProxyData(Settings->Sock, PCHAR(&LoginReply), sizeof(LoginReply), Settings->Func) != TRUE)
{
    // close the connection...
    return FALSE;
}

if (LoginReply.Status != 0)
{
    // close the connection...
    return FALSE;
}

/*
The SOCKS request is formed as follows:
    +----+-----+-------+------+----------+----------+
    |VER | CMD |  RSV  | ATYP | DST.ADDR | DST.PORT |
    +----+-----+-------+------+----------+----------+
    | 1  |  1  | X'00' |  1   | Variable |    2     |
    +----+-----+-------+------+----------+----------+
*/

socks5_request Request;

// I'm assuming that SOCKS5_Header is only the 1st 4 bytes of the request...
if (Http::ReadProxyData(Settings->Sock, PCHAR(&Request.SOCKS5_Header), sizeof(socks5_header), Settings->Func) != TRUE)
{
    // close the connection...
    return FALSE;
}

if (Request.SOCKS5_Header.Version != 5) /*SOCKS Version 5*/
{
    // I'm assuming you have something like this defined.
    // Adjust this code as needed. What is important is that
    // you need to send back a Reply code before disconnecting...
    socks5_reply Reply;
    UCHAR dst[6] = {0}; // <-- if socks5_reply doesn't have DST.ADDR/DST.PORT fields of its own...

    Reply.SOCKS5_Header.Version = 5;
    Reply.SOCKS5_Header.Status = 1; /*general SOCKS server failure*/
    Reply.SOCKS5_Header.Reserved = 0;
    Reply.SOCKS5_Header.AddressType = 1;

    Http::SendProxyData(Settings->Sock, PCHAR(&Reply.SOCKS5_Header), sizeof(socks5_header), Settings->Func);
    Http::SendProxyData(Settings->Sock, PCHAR(dst), sizeof(dst), Settings->Func);

    // close the connection...
    return FALSE;
}

if (Request.SOCKS5_Header.Command != 1) /*CONNECT*/
{
    // same as above...
    Reply.SOCKS5_Header.Status = 7; /*Command not supported*/
    ...
    return FALSE;
}

if (Request.SOCKS5_Header.AddressType != 1) /*IPv4*/
{
    // same as above...
    Reply.SOCKS5_Header.Status = 8; /*Address type not supported*/
    ...
    return FALSE;
}

// finish reading DST.ADDR and DST.PORT fields into Request...
// use Request as needed...
// send a Reply accordingly...
```

Comment: I tried to commit your code into mine. However, it still failed on this recv `PCHAR(&Request.SOCKS5_Header)`.

Comment: It is hard to answer that when you haven't shown what `socks5_login` and `socks5_request` are actually declared as, or how `Http::SendProxyData()` and  `Http::ReadProxyData()` are actually implemented. How do you expect people to help you when you don't provide a [mcve]? In any case, I suggest you use a packet sniffer like Wireshark to look at the actual SOCKS traffic and make sure everything is being formatted correctly on the wire. Chances are, it is not.